# Pcointing to the previous node of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have defined the node of a linked list like below:

(The "next" part points to the next node and the "previous" part points to the previous node)

```
typedef struct node{
char val;
struct node* next;
struct node* previous;
}node_t;
```

And I have initialized three nodes like this:

```
node_t* head=NULL;
head=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->val='a';
head->previous=NULL;
head->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->next->val='b';
head->next->previous=head;
head->next->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
head->next->next->val='c';
head->next->next->previous=head->next;
head->next->next->next=NULL;
node_t*current=head;
```

And my goal is that whenever the user type "R",then our current pointer will point to the next node and whenever the user type "L",then our current pointer will point to the previous node and whenever we type "P" then we can type a letter (char c) to add this letter as a new node before the current node.

my code for this part is like this:

```
char input;
scanf("%c",&input);
if(input=='R'){
       current=current->next;
   }
if(input=='L'){
       current=current->previous;
   }
if(input=='P'){
       char c;
       scanf(" %c",&c);
       node_t * new=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
       new->val=c;
       new->next=current;
       new->previous=current->previous;
       current->previous->next=new;//need help to correct this part
   }
```

The "R" and "L" part works correctly but I don't know why the "P" part doesn't add the node.

for example:

input:

R

P j

output:

jbc

but the output of this code is still bc.

Comment: Seems that you need also current->previous = new; Write some functions to insert, delete etc. Btw you will get segfault if you try to insert before the first node. And you can't insert after the last one.

Comment: Did you use pen and paper to "play" everything through? Use drawn boxes for each node and arrows from one box to another for the pointer. Use the word "NULL" to point to with pointers which are init to NULL. Then erase pointers and draw them elsewhere whenever you assign to a pointer. If you do that, does the dual linked chain look like expected when you are done with your code?

Comment: Your ouput starts from `head, doesn't it? Find the part of your code which actually changes the content of the variable `head`. In the code you have shown I can't find that part.

Comment: You need to set `current->next->previous` too, don’t you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the P case does not change `current->next->previous` and does not change `current`.

You may also wish to consider circumstances in which you might change `head`.